# Pandas groupby and rolling window

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I`m trying to calculate the sum of one field for a specific period of time, after grouping function is applied.

My dataset look like this:

```
Date          Company   Country    Sold
01.01.2020       A          BE       1
02.01.2020       A          BE       0
03.01.2020       A          BE       1
03.01.2020       A          BE       1
04.01.2020       A          BE       1
05.01.2020       B          DE       1
06.01.2020       B          DE       0
```

I would like to add a new column per each row, that calculates the sum of Sold (per each group "Company, Country" for the last 7 days - not including the current day

```
Date          Company   Country    Sold      LastWeek_Count
01.01.2020       A          BE       1           0
02.01.2020       A          BE       0           1
03.01.2020       A          BE       1           1
03.01.2020       A          BE       1           1
04.01.2020       A          BE       1           3
05.01.2020       B          DE       1           0
06.01.2020       B          DE       0           1
```

I tried the following, but it is also including the current date, and it gives differnt values for the same date, i.e 03.01.2020

```
df['LastWeek_Count'] = df.groupby(['Company', 'Country']).rolling(7, on ='Date')['Sold'].sum().reset_index()
```

Is there a buildin function in pandas that I can use to perform these calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to first consolidate the **Sold** value of each group (['Date', 'Company', 'Country']) on a single line using a temporary DF. 
After that, apply your `.groupby` with `.rolling` with an interval of 8 rows. 
After calculating the sum, subtract the value of each line with the value in **Sold** column and add that column in the original DF with `.merge`

```
#convert Date column to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
#create a temporary DataFrame
df2 = df.groupby(['Date', 'Company', 'Country'])['Sold'].sum().reset_index()
#calc the lastweek
df2['LastWeek_Count'] = (df2.groupby(['Company', 'Country'])
                            .rolling(8, min_periods=1, on = 'Date')['Sold']
                            .sum().reset_index(drop=True)
                        ) 
#subtract the value of 'lastweek' from the current 'Sold'
df2['LastWeek_Count'] = df2['LastWeek_Count'] - df2['Sold']
#add th2 new column in the original DF
df.merge(df2.drop(columns=['Sold']), on = ['Date', 'Company', 'Country'])
#output:
    Date        Company Country Sold    LastWeek_Count
0   2020-01-01  A       BE      1       0.0
1   2020-01-02  A       BE      0       1.0
2   2020-01-03  A       BE      1       1.0
3   2020-01-03  A       BE      1       1.0
4   2020-01-04  A       BE      1       3.0
5   2020-01-05  B       DE      1       0.0
6   2020-01-06  B       DE      0       1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `.rolling` window of `8` and then subtract the sum of the Date (for each grouped row) to effectively get the previous 7 days. For this sample data, we should also pass `min_periods=1` (otherwise you will get `NaN` values, but for your actual dataset, you will need to decide what you want to do with windows that are < `8`).

Then from the `.rolling` window of `8`, simply do another `.groupby` of the relevant columns but also include `Date` this time, and take the `max` value of the newly created `LastWeek_Count` column. You need to take the `max`, because you have multiple records per day, so by taking the max, you are taking the total aggregated amount per `Date`.

Then, create a series that takes the grouped by `sum` per `Date`. In the final step subtract the sum by date from the rolling 8-day max, which is a workaround to how you can get the sum of the previous 7 days, as there is not a parameter for an offset with `.rolling`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df['LastWeek_Count'] = df.groupby(['Company', 'Country']).rolling(8, min_periods=1, on='Date')['Sold'].sum().reset_index()['Sold']
df['LastWeek_Count'] = df.groupby(['Company', 'Country', 'Date'])['LastWeek_Count'].transform('max')
s = df.groupby(['Company', 'Country', 'Date'])['Sold'].transform('sum')
df['LastWeek_Count'] = (df['LastWeek_Count']-s).astype(int)

Out[17]: 
        Date Company Country  Sold  LastWeek_Count
0 2020-01-01       A      BE     1               0
1 2020-01-02       A      BE     0               1
2 2020-01-03       A      BE     1               1
3 2020-01-03       A      BE     1               1
4 2020-01-04       A      BE     1               3
5 2020-01-05       B      DE     1               0
6 2020-01-06       B      DE     0               1
```